# Error when creating a scheduler task with the schtasks utility

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am trying to make my python script create a scheduled task via

```
subprocess.call(r"<string for cmd utility here"),
```

however, I get an error when creating the scheduled task via the schtasks utility (both via subprocess and via direct interaction with cmd).

I tried

```
SCHTASKS /Create /s \\%computername% /U %username% /P Password123# /RU "SYSTEM" /SC onstart /TN mytask /TR C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\myexecutable.exe
```

but this yields "User credentials are not allowed on the local machine.". I tried

```
schtasks /create /S \\%computername% /RU %userdomain%\%username% /RP Password123# /SC onstart /TN mytask /TR C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\myexecutable.exe
```

(following https://thebackroomtech.com/2009/04/06/windows-2008-schtasks-error-user-credentials-are-not-allowed-on-the-local-machine/), yielding "ERROR: Access is denied".

Adding /IT to modify the scheduled task to run only when the user is logged on also does not help.

I imagine a community member has tried what I am attempting to do before, so a solution or hint is greatly appreciated. Kind regards.

Comment: You can EITHER run it with an user account (`/U`), OR with the System account (`/RU`) The site you linked to, explicitly tells *use /RU and /RP **instead** of /U and /P*

Comment: I see. That was an oversight on my part in the first schtasks call.  Thank you for pointing it out. In the second I used /RU and /RP as intended though.
I could make it work via executing cmd as the administrator and issuing: schtasks /create /ru "SYSTEM" /sc onstart /tn mytask /tr C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\myexecutable.exe

Comment: correct, you need admin rights to schedule a task as SYSTEM. Being able to execute anything in an elevated context as a "normal" user would be a big security risk.

Comment: I should also mention that `schtasks` is not a `cmd.exe` command. It is an independent executable file, which accepts arguments. As such you should be able to run it without any need to involve `cmd.exe`. ```import subprocess```, ```subprocess.call('"C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe" /create ...')``` , and certainly without `shell=True`. I have therefore removed your [[tag:cmd]] tag.